# Parse xml file with multiple elements via jackson

Tags: android, xml, jackson, xml-parsing, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have an xml file like this:

```
<TABLES>
<TABLE NAME="abcd" TIME="2013.05.27 00:00:00" >
<LINES>
<LINE TIME="2013.05.27 00:00:00" BEGINE="787465" END="787465"/>
</LINES>
<SPECIAL>
<DAY MASK="128" DATE="16714778" />
<WEEK NAME="abcde" PARAM="128" />
</SPECIAL> 
</TABLE>
</TABLES>
```

Problem is that, within the `SPECIAL` tag there are 2 types of elements `DAY` and `WEEK`. I am not able to parse it via jackson, is there any special way to handle it? I can parse the rest via POJO without any problem, but for special I need to set up 2 different classes

```
// DAY
class SPECIAL(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MASK")
    val mask: String,

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DATE")
    val date: Int,
)

// WEEK
class SPECIAL(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NAME")
    val name: String,

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PARAM")
    val param: Int,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Special has two different tags `DAY` and `Week` so you can segregate them into two POJO classes as

```
data class DAY(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Date") val date: String, @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "MASK")val mask: String)

data class WEEK(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "PARAM") val param: String,@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Name") val name: String)
```

and use them in SPECIAL class as:

```
data class SPECIAL(@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "WEEK") val week: WEEK, @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DAY") val day: DAY)
```

---

To make the `SPECIAL` field optional, mark that field as nullable in your `TABLE` class using `?` as:

```
data class TABLE(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SPECIAL") val special: SPECIAL?,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "NAME") val name: String,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "TIME") val time: String
)
```

and `SPECIAL` class as

```
data class SPECIAL(
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "WEEK") var week: WEEK?,
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DAY") var day: DAY?
)
```

[View Complete Source Code](https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/community_solutions/blob/master/kotlin/JacksonOptionalDataParsing.kt)

Comment: OK, I did like proposed week or day is not mandatory so I made them optional, but then I had error Unrecognized field, not marked as ignorable. And when I annotated classed with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) parsing is finished wothout error, there is correct number of SPECIAL objects but in all of them DAY and WEEK is always null

Comment: @maxxxo `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` will avoid the serialization and deserialization so better use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` for optional values and also use `var` with nullable fields `var day: DAY? = null `. Though it's better to mention the requirement once in question or post another question

Comment: I tried the Include annotation and optionals, but did not helped, this is the error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "NAME" (class *.Special), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "DAY", "WEEK", "day", "week"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 26, column: 58] (through reference chain: >*.Table["SPECDAYS"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->*.SpecDay["NAME"]) Main problem is that in Special Jackson expects properties from Day/ Week not Day/Week. I tried also to set isAttribute = true but no change

Comment: When I copied parameters from Day and Week into Special it worked fine